# Completion handler in cell

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, swift3

I want if something happening in cell(ex button action) - use completion handler:
But not sure this is correct way:

In Cell Class I have:

```
class SwitchTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

var completion: ((_ mark: Void) -> Void)?
```

In my Table view CellForRow:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = …
    cell.completion = { 
         //* here my code *//
}
```

Comment: Are you facing any issue ? because it looks ok

Comment: Where are you calling `completion`? it might be optional...

Comment: @NiravD I just not sure what this is correct

Comment: @IlyaChikmarev Yes its looks okay also this is not the place for code review

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just made one block for button is selected or not and it's worked for me.I just declare "didTapPickUpButtonBlock" and use it in may UITableview cell method.I think it's pretty simple.I hope it will work for you.

```
     var didTapPickUpButtonBlock: ((_ sender: Any) -> Void)? = nil

     weak var weakCell: CheckoutCell? = cell
     cell.didTapPickUpButtonBlock = {(_ sender: Any) -> Void in
     var btn: UIButton? = (sender as? UIButton)
     if btn?.tag == 100 {
         weakCell?.deliveryButton?.isSelected = false
         weakCell?.pickupButton?.isSelected = true
     } 
     else {
         weakCell?.deliveryButton?.isSelected = true
         weakCell?.pickupButton?.isSelected = false
     }
  }`
```